# Trying to zoom in on image over hover

Tags: html, css

I am creating a website for a project and got stuck with an issue.
I was trying to implement the hover feature, where when I hover over the image it gets zoomed in. That part works nicely, however, I was having an issue when I hover over the last book in the first row. When I hover over that, the entire screen becomes glitchy. This feature is not working as I hoped, i.e. smooth and good to work with. I have attached the image and the code I have.

Thanks for any help!

```
.books img{
width:200px;
height:300px;
}

.books img:hover {
  position: relative;
  left: 45px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  display: block;
}
```

[image]

I found some code online using -mox-transform and -webkit-transform, however, I have never worked with that before. This seemed complex for me. Any suggestions if I should learn how that works instead of perfecting the above code?

Comment: please add a working code snippet. That will help us to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

By increasing the `width` and `height` on hover the surrounding layout must adapt to that size change. The browser must move the surrounding elements to provide the space for the larger element, that is why it is glitchy.

If you want to do it properly, you will probably have to use [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform), as you mentioned.

For your use case it should not be hard. Try this:

```css
.books img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    transition: transform 200ms; /* optional transition with 200ms duration */
}

.books img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1); /* scale to 110% */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to use is scale property to scale the image. Change your code to this

```
.books img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

This should do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use [transform](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) CSS Property with `scale()` which is used to increase or decrease the size of an element

```
.books img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```